# Инструмент поиска на сайт с большой базой

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, поиск

У меня есть сайт, который я написал на Yii2. Сайт использует очень большую базу данных. Есть таблицы по 100 млн строк и больше. При поиске используется много **JOIN**.

На сколько я смог - я оптимизировал базу. Но этой скорости все равно не хватает, сайт работает не совсем быстро.

Знаю и инструменте [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), но не работал с ним, из-за этого не могу понять, подходит ли он для таких задач.

Может кто сталкивался с таким - подскажите в какую сторону смотреть.

P.S. База данных - MYSQL (innoDB). Если можно использовать какую то другую базу и можно быстро эту перевести и переписать запросы - буду благодарен за подсказку

Уточнения по вопросу:

размер базы примерно 250Gb

поиск по артикулях автозапчастей

запрос выполняется примерно 1-2 минуты

Comment: "очень большую" - какого размера? "много" - сколько? "этой скорости" - какой скорости? "не совсем быстро" - это как? "для таких задач" - для каких задач? Не вопрос, а какая-то сплошная вода. Добавьте конкретики, приведите структуру базы, типичные запросы и их узкие места.  Sphinx - это инструмент для полнотекстового поиска.

Comment: Вы говорите про поиск в заголовке, но в теме говорите про `join` (акцентируете на нем внимание) так что именно у вас? проблема с поиском или с `join` или и то и другое? Приведите абстрактный пример, простенький, чтобы мы поняли что у вас происходит и мы тогда сможет конкретно что-то посоветовать.

Answer (score 4):

В процессе оптимизации никогда нету предела :). Проверьте по пунктам:

- попробуйте денормализовать БД, чтобы избежать большого кол-ва джоинов
- постройте составные индексы по постоянно фильтруемым полям
- проверьте скорость диска на сервере, т.к. в работе с реляционными СУБД (прим. MySQL, Postgresql) SSD - это must have, это один из ключевых параметров в скорости БД в целом.
- если к БД слишком много запросов на чтение и запись одновременно, добавьте отдельную реплику slave и выполняйте поиск только по данной реплике

Если же не помогает и это, тогда воспользуйтесь решениями, которые специально разработанны для быстрого полнотекстового поиска такими как **ElasticSearch** либо **Sphinx**. Почитайте про оптимизацию: [тут](https://ruhighload.com/server/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) - вполне просто и доходчиво разобраны основные кейсы.

Comment: Интересно, а кто это минусанул? Почему не написал, что в ответе не так? Человек задал абстрактный вопрос, ему дали абстрактный ответ, причем довольно неплохой